# Rails: Cannot set option by using method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example here is my paperclip configuration. Here is my model file:

```
class File < ApplicationRecord  
   belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
   has_attached_file(:attach_file, local_option)
end
```

In this model file, I have defined two option named `local_option` and `s3_option`.

```
def local_option
  {
    :storage => :filesystem,
    :path    => 'public/:class/:id/:basename.:extension'
  }
end

def s3_option
  {
    :storage    => :s3,
    :s3_headers => lambda { |attachment| {'Content-Type' => attachment.attach_file_content_type} }
  }
end
```

When I run, I meet this error:

> method_missing': undefined local variable or method `local_option' for
>   Class:0x007fc9be09dac8>  (NameError)

I don't know why ruby/rails doesn't see `local_option` method. Please tell me how.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be class instance method, not instance method.

```
def self.local_option
  {
    storage: :filesystem,
    path:    'public/:class/:id/:basename.:extension'
  }
end
```

And voila - error is gone.

**Advice**: since it is non-changing data, I'd put it into a constant:

```
LOCAL_FILE_OPTIONS = {
  storage: :filesystem,
  path:    'public/:class/:id/:basename.:extension'
}.freeze
```

Now

```
has_attached_file(:attach_file, LOCAL_FILE_OPTIONS)
```

Comment: I have changed as you said, but the error still be same.

Comment: @TrầnKimDự impossible.

Comment: Here is my full code: https://paste.ofcode.org/FhPLywqXz4aY7buBha8DRg and I still meet same error ;(

Comment: If I use constant solution, I meet error: `uninitialized constant Attachment::LOCAL_FILE_OPTIONS`.

Comment: @TrầnKimDự this is not really possible. double check naming, check, if you're using hte constant in the correct class. restart the server. Debug

Comment: I still cannot find error. the file name is same with class name, no problem. But can I ask, why you know  method `has_attached_file` should use class method because I see it looks like normal method. thanks

Comment: @TrầnKimDự `has_attached_file` is called in the context of the class, thus it is it's instance method (class' singleton method).

Comment: @TrầnKimDự in your question you show `File` class, whereas in the picture of code you show `Attachment` class. Maybe it's the reason - you define/ues the method in the wrong place.

Comment: In fact, that file named Attachment. I just renamed File for clear purpose :D I still don't know what is the problem. I currently resolve by create two different classes: one is `LocalAttachment` and one is `AmazonAttachment` with its own purpose.